# How do I access a node.js app through the host of an adhoc network?

Tags: ad-hoc-network, node.js

Running `ifconfig` tells me that the IP should be `192.168.0.1` however this does not permit me to access the app. I'm running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to access a node.js app running on port 9990 that's running on the same Pi. I'm trying to access this on a Mac that's connected to the adhoc network created by the Pi. I have tried port forwarding the port too but this hasn't worked. I have tried typing in '192.168.0.1:9990' into my browser on my Mac but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi Jake, I'm running Raspbian on a raspberry pi and I'm trying to access a node.js app running on port 9990 that's running on the same pi. I'm trying to access this on a mac that's connected to the adhoc network created by the pi. I type in the ip that ifconfig states is the ip and also the port but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Hey Jacob, try accessing it using the url http://192.168.0.1:9990

Comment: @Arthur I have tried accessing through that method but it didn't work. I have edited the question Jake to make this more specific. My apologies.